# setTimeout on Hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to implement a function setTimout on this hover. 
http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/33/

```
    $(function() {
    $("#moving .wrapper").mousemove(function (e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $(this).children(".hidden-content").css("left", relX);
    });

    $("#static .wrapper").hover(function (e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $(this).children(".hidden-content").css("left", relX);
    });
});
```

I think I have a problem with parameters, cause coordonates are re-evaluated each mouse move

Comment: What are you trying to do? As this is an event handler, it will display the hidden part based on the last hover event, where e.pageX can be different every time.

Comment: What are you asking? Your fiddle only has one function, and what do you want the timeout for?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to get in result? Please improve your question as it is not clear at this moment.

Comment: I would like when cursor is on Visible content (Hover me static), the hidden content appears after 2-3 seconds not instantly.

Answer (score 0):

hover work in two stage

```
$("#static .wrapper").hover(function (e) {
    // first stage it is wok on mouseover
}, function (e) {
    // second stage it is wok on mouseout
});
```

now you can apply your setimeout in this according to your requirement 
reference **[HOVER](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timeout `onmouseenter` and put the code that actual shows and positions the hidden content into a separate function:

```
(function () {
    var delay = 400,
        timeout;

    function showChild(posLeft) {
        $(this).children(".hidden-content").css('left', posLeft).show();
    }

    $("#static .wrapper").mouseenter(function (e) {
        var that = this,    
            event = e;

        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timout = setTimeout(function () {
            var parentOffset = $(that).parent().offset(); 
            var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            showChild.call(that, relX);
        }, delay);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        $(this).children(".hidden-content").hide();
    });
}());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtU2w/)